# How works super().get_queryset() in Django?

Tags: django

I am trying to get a queryset of questions that have publication date before today's date, but I am getting an error
`in get_queryset raise ImproperlyConfigured(django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: IndexView is missing a QuerySet. Define IndexView.model, IndexView.queryset, or override IndexView.get_queryset().`

My code:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

But this code works:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a parent with a `get_queryset()`, but that queryset does not come out of "thin air": you either should specify a [**`.queryset`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.queryset) or [**`.model`** attribute <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.model), such that Django can construct the basic queryset:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

here we however can work with the database clock with [**`Now`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#now), and thus don't need to override `.get_queryset(…)` at all:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=Now())
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
```